# Drools specified encoding not taking effect

Tags: java, drools, kie

In my drl file, I'm using German characters such as Umlauts or ß. Thus, I am setting the encoding to UTF-8 with the overloaded constructor when creating the Resource for the Kie File System. 
However, after firing the rules on the inserted Fact Drools does not seem to apply the specified encoding. I insert the fact, and if the condition is true to that fact it should modify the Action1 (String) attribute of the fact to "Rückfrage" and return the modified fact. However, when I look at the retrieved bean's Action1 attribute I am seeing "RÃ¼ckfrage" instead of "Rückfrage". I tried both UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 encoding. Any ideas what's wrong?

Drools 7.13

KieSessionGenerator:

```
public KieSessionGenerator() {
    KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();

    KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
    kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource(drlFile, "UTF-8"));

    KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem);
    kieBuilder.buildAll();
    KieModule kieModule = kieBuilder.getKieModule();

    KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieModule.getReleaseId());

    kieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession();
}
```

Snippet from DRL:

```
rule "813"
when
    $bean : Bean(longDesc == "Infektion")
then
    $bean.setAction1("Rückfrage");
end
```

Inserting the fact:

```
public Bean lookupBean(Bean bean) {
    kieSessionGenerator.getKieSession().insert(bean);
    kieSessionGenerator.getKieSession().fireAllRules();
    return bean;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, it is an encoding problem and not the problem with Drools. I suspect the drlFile is not saved in UTF-8 encoding to disk. What editor do you use to edit drlFile? Find an editor that shows the actual encoding of the file or set the encoding in the editor to UTF-8 and overwrite the file.

Comment: The encoding of the DRL file was UTF-8, but the JVM was running with the default CP-1252. As soon as I set the encoding of the JVM to UTF-8 all works just fine.